# What is worker_processes in Nginx and how much is there on Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, heroku, webpack, worker-process

I am reading on interent but I simple don't get it. What is worker_processes and what do we use it for? The reason I am asking is that I am configuring Nginx to work with Heroku apps. Everything works great but I am trying to optimize Nginx settings.

One of those settings is worker_processes.
On the interent I founf example to set it up like this inside my nginx.conf.erb

`worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>`

How much of this worker processes is there on Heroku free plan and paid plan?

Answer (score 0):

Worker_process- https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_processes

It is a number of process that Nginx starts to handle traffic. This configuration depends of the number of CPUs and Hard Drives available in your environment.

Recommends starts in auto and if you suffer with problem adjust to the number of cores or threads.